# Combine a array of live audio streams and play it as one audio stream(Without Craks between two streams)

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have a list of Array(live audio stream 5mins clips) and i want to combine it as a one file and play it in a player as it is in the order of the array.

```
function init() {
  // Fix up prefixing
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  context = new AudioContext();

  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
      audio stream 1,
      audio stream 2,
      audio stream 3
    ],
    finishedLoading
    );

  bufferLoader.load();
}
```

**which is the best way to merge the multiple streams.**

```
 function play() {
      //end of stream has been reached
      if (audiobuffer.length === 0) { return; }
      let source = context.createBufferSource();

      //get the latest buffer that should play next
      source.buffer = audiobuffer.shift();
      source.connect(context.destination);

      //add this function as a callback to play next buffer
      //when current buffer has reached its end 
      source.onended = play;
      source.start();
    }
```

Comment: That looks good, are there problems with it? The audio api's are designed so that you create a new AudioNode each time you need to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`AudioBufferSourceNode.start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) with a `when` parameter to schedule playback of an AudioNode for a specific time.

For your example you'll want to create all your nodes and then schedule them to start one after another.

```
function play() {
    let totalTime = 0;

    audioBuffers.forEach(buffer => {
        const source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(context.currentTime + totalTime);
        totalTime += source.duration;
    });
}
```